# automatically calculate value over several tables with python, including filtering

Tags: python, math, arcgis, calculation, arcpy

I need to write a python script to automatically calculate costs into a given column by combining several tables (if possible using arcpy in ArcMap 10.7) but I’m struggling to do that since I’ve never actually done something like that.
Hence here I am, hoping that some kind soul in this community might be able to help me.
My tables have several columns, but I just listed the onces relevant for my calculations, for simplicity the tablenames will just be table1, table2, table3. Unfortunately, I don’t have any dummy data that I could post here…

My tables:

- Table1, Columns:  area(int), number(string), code(int), section(string)
- Table2, Columns : code(int), a_value(double)
- Table3, Columns : number(string), b _value(double),costs_calc(double)

Table1 and Table2 are connected via the ID in the respective column «code»
; Table1 and Table3 are connected via the number in the respective column «number»

Goal : script should automatically calculate costs in column «costs_calc» from values stored in 3 different tables…

Process I want to script (or how I figured the steps to get a result look like):

> Step 1:  Filter in Table1, from column « section » all rows with the
> value «B» *(only those rows with this value are needed for further
> calculation, the other rows should not be included)*
>
> Step 2: Multiply Values in «a_value» (Table2) with all values from
> «area» (Table1) *(for all rows filtered in Step 1 – of course Step 1 and Step 2 can be swaped if it’s easier (not sure))  --Interim results could be written into a temporary table or into a new column in table1 – whatever is easier…*
>
> Step 3: Summarize the result calculated in Step 2 according to their number (Table1) *(here I want all the calculated results combined/summarized according to their number -- after calculation there are for example 5 results for number 12345 (because their «code» is different) and these should be summarized into) interim results could be written into a temporary table or a new column in table3*

Example for what I mean with "summarize calculated interim results (costs_interim) according to number", that's what should happen:
[Table after calculation step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDcKg.png)
[Table after summarizing step 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDnIG.png)

> Step 4: Results calculated in Step 3 (summarized values) should be multiplied with the values in column « b_value ». The results of this step will also be the final results and are thus written into the column «costs_calc» (Table3)

I know I can execute the first step by using the SearchCursor(arcpy)function but beyond that, I’m lost...
Hence I also have no code up to now except for import arcpy, math, etc. and setting the environment and a first try with the SearchCursor-function..

I’d be so very grateful for some hints, solutions or ideas!!

my first try:

```
fc="table1" fields = ['section','area'] delimfield = arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(fc, fields[1]) cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fields, delimfield +"= 'B'")

#Open a searchcursor
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor("c:/Users/myuser/mydatabase/table1",
                          fields="section")

#Iterate through the rows in the cursor and print out the section value.
    for row in rows:
        print("section: {0}".format(
            row.getValue("B")))
```

I've also added the mentioned steps as followed into the code:

```
# Local variables:
table1 = "C:\\Users\\myuser\\Documents\\mydatabase.gdb\\table1"
table2 = "C:\\Users\\myuser\\Documents\\mydatabase.gdb\\table2"
table3 = "C:\\Users\\myuser\\Documents\\mydatabase.gdb\\table3"
table1_a = table1
table1_b = table1_a
table1_c = table1_b
table1_d = table1_c
table1_e = table1_d
table3_a = table3
table1_end = table1_e

# Process: Add field in table1 for interim results
arcpy.AddField_management(talbe1, "costs_interim", "DOUBLE", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")

# Process: Join table1 and table2 via shared fields "code"
arcpy.JoinField_management(table_b, "code", table2, "code", "")

# Process: calculate field costs_interim
arcpy.CalculateField_management(table1_c, "costs_interim", "!area!* !a_value!", "")

#Summarize costs_interim according to their number

# Process: add field in table3
arcpy.AddField_management(table3, "costs_calc_interim", "DOUBLE", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")

# Process: join table1 and table3 via shared field "number"
arcpy.JoinField_management(table1_d, "number", table3_a, "number", "")

# Process: calculate endresult into field "cost_calc"
arcpy.CalculateField_management(table1_e, "costs_calc", "!costs_calc_interim! * !b_value! / 100", "")
```

The things here is that I generate new columns (which is ok) but with every join or calculation a new table gets generated. I'd prefer the tables to be generated temporarily, so that the final result is not in a new table but written into table3 as described in the intro.

What is still missing, is how to summarize the calculated field "costs__interim" according to their value in the field/column "number" before joining the tables in the step afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

For step 2:
I propose that you Join ob Table 1 and Table 2 on the "Code" column. This should give you a Table containing the columns from both Tables.
Next, create a new field in the resulting join table that calculates the value from column "a_field" multiplied by value from column "area"

Here are links to documentations for join and creating fields

Join: https://pro.arcgis.com/de/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/data-management/join-field.htm

Create field: https://pro.arcgis.com/de/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/data-management/add-field.htm

For step 3
Here is a documentation to summarize fields

https://pro.arcgis.com/de/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/analysis/summary-statistics.htm

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thanks @MizzMatze
Yes, I've done the joins, but don't know how to make the generated table into temporary tables.  I've updated the script part in my question.

thank you for the hint with the summary-statistics. I had tried using the function 
> arcpy.Statistics_analysis() 
but somehow couldn't get it to work (probably only for ArcgisPro?). I'll try again since you had the same idea - so I know I wasn't completely off. 

I'm very thankful for your input!

Answer (score 0):

Update:
Instead of arcpy.da.SearchCursor() I used arcpy.TableSelect
afterwards as mentioned already in the questions just adding fields (arcpy.AddField) and joining (arcpy.JoinField), as well as the summary statistics (finally seems to work as well).
Once I test it and confirm it's running, I'll post the final code.

Still open for any inputs or ideas though

Answer (score 0):

So the final and mostly cleaned up code looks like this:

```
# Import system modules
import arcpy, arcgisscripting
from arcpy import env
from datetime import datetime
import os, os.path, sys, time, datetime, traceback, string, math, getpass
from re import sub
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import locale;
os.environ["PYTHONIOENCODING"] = "utf-8";
import re
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

###############################################################################################################
# Variables
# Workspace - db
print "******************************************************************************************"
print "Workspace db"
print "******************************************************************************************"
workspace = "C:\datasources\MyProject\db" + '\\'
print 'Workspace:',                 workspace
db = workspace + "mydatabase.gdb"
backupdb = db.replace(".gdb", "_copy.gdb")
print 'db:       ',                 db
tempdb = db + '\\' + "tempDB.gdb"
tempgebuehren = workspace + "mydatabase_temp.gdb"
###############################################################################################################

# Create a copy of the db
arcpy.Copy_management(db, backupdb)

#User and timestamp
currentUser = getpass.getuser().upper()
arcpy.AddMessage("User: " + currentUser)
#currentTimestamp = str(datetime.datetime.now())
#arcpy.AddMessage("Timestamp: " + currentTimestamp)
expTimestamp = '''def add_date():
  import datetime
  return datetime.datetime.now()'''
# exp = '''def add_date():
#  import time
#  return time.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")'''

#set workspace environment
try:
   arcpy.env.workspace = db
   arcpy.AddMessage('Database read successfully ...')
except:
   arcpy.AddMessage('Database not found. Please try again')

#create temporary table for all calculations processes
try:
   arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(workspace, "mydatabase_temp.gdb")
   arcpy.AddMessage('Database created successfully ...')
except:
   arcpy.AddMessage('Database could not be created. Please try again')

# set script parameter
TABLE1 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
if TABLE1 == '#' or not TABLE1:
    TABLE1 = db + '\\' + "TABLE1" # provide a default value if unspecified


table2 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
if table2 == '#' or not table2:
    table2 = db + '\\' + "AV" + '\\' + "table2" # provide a default value if unspecified


TABLE3 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
if TABLE3 == '#' or not TABLE3:
    TABLE3 = db + '\\' + "TABLE3" # provide a default value if unspecified


# Check if the Column u_value_type contains any NULL values and replace them with 0
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(table2, ["u_value_type"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] == None:
            row[0] = 0
            cursor.updateRow(row)

arcpy.AddMessage('The column u_value_type contained NULL values and they were successfully replaced with 0')

del row

# Create a copy of the db
arcpy.Copy_management(db, backupdb)


# local variables (generated temporarily)
table2__2_ = table2

TABLE1_temp = workspace + '\\' + "mydatabase_temp.gdb" + '\\' + "TABLE1_temp"
TABLE1_temp__2_ = TABLE1_temp
TABLE1_temp__3_ = TABLE1_temp__2_
TABLE1_temp__4_ = TABLE1_temp__3_

table2__3_ = table2__2_
table2__4_ = table2__3_

TABLE3 = db + '\\' + "\\TABLE3"

TABLE1_SUM = workspace + '\\' + "mydatabase_temp.gdb" + '\\' + "TABLE1_SUM"


try:
# Calculation process
    arcpy.AddMessage('Starting calculation process ...')
# for column "sektion" select all rows with value "B" in table "TABLE1"
    arcpy.TableSelect_analysis(TABLE1, TABLE1_temp, "SEKTION = 'B'")
    arcpy.AddMessage('Filter table: ok')
# add a temporary field for later calculation results to table TABLE1
    arcpy.AddField_management(TABLE1_temp, "u_area_fees", "DOUBLE", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
# join fields from table TABLE1 with table TABLE3 on art=code for later calculation over both tables
    arcpy.JoinField_management(TABLE1_temp__2_, "ART", TABLE3, "CODE", "CODE;u_cvalue")
    arcpy.AddMessage('join tables in temporary gdb: ok')
# calculate field from values of joined tables into newly added field
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(TABLE1_temp__3_, "u_area_fees", "!FLAECHE! * !u_cvalue!", "PYTHON", "")
    arcpy.AddMessage('temporary calculations: ok')
# summary statistics to merge all results according to their number
    arcpy.Statistics_analysis(TABLE1_temp__4_, TABLE1_SUM, "u_area_fees SUM", "NUMMER")
    arcpy.AddMessage('summarize fields: ok')
# join fields from tables fpr TABLE1 on table2 on number=number
    arcpy.JoinField_management(table2__2_, "NUMMER", TABLE1_SUM, "NUMMER", "NUMMER;SUM_u_area_fees")
    arcpy.AddMessage('join tables: ok')
# add field for results
    arcpy.AddField_management(table2__3_, "u_area_fees_noncalculated", "DOUBLE", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "", "")
    arcpy.AddMessage('field added')
# calculate field
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(table2__3_, "u_area_fees_noncalculated", "(!u_value_type! / 100) * !SUM_u_area_fees!", "PYTHON", "")
    arcpy.AddMessage('interim results calculated')
# calculate endresult rounded
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(table2__4_, "u_area_fees_calculated", "math.ceil(!u_area_fees_noncalculated!)", "PYTHON", "")
    arcpy.AddMessage('...calculation process finished without errors')
except Exception,e:
    arcpy.AddMessage('Something went wrong. Please try again')
    arcpy.AddMessage("Fehler: " + str(e))


#delete temporary fields in table table2
try:
  arcpy.DeleteField_management(table2, ["NUMMER_1", "SUM_u_area_fees"])
  arcpy.AddMessage('Temporary fields successfully deleted...')
except:
   arcpy.AddMessage('Something went wrong, fields could not be deleted. Please try again')


#delete temporary FileGBD
try:
   arcpy.Delete_management(tempmydatabase)
   arcpy.AddMessage('Temporary database successfully deleted...')
except:
   arcpy.AddMessage('Ups, Something went wrong, could not delete Database. Please try again')
```